# Submitting 2 strings to mysql database

Tags: php

Currently I have these strings and I need to make it so that they = 1 string instead of 2 but can still print different results.

```
$title2 = $html2->find('#wrapper > div > section > main > div > article > div.details > h1 > strong',0);
$title = $html2->find('#wrapper > div > section > main > div > article > div.details > h1 > span',0);
print $title2 = $title2->plaintext;
print ' - ';
print $title = $title->plaintext;
```

Currently returns something that looks like this. **Artist Name - Song Name**

But I need to some how put it into my database and it's not working when I do this.

```
`title` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$title2,$title)."',
```

What can I do so that the output in my database table looks exactly like what's being printed out?

Comment: It so sample of php language
$title1 = mysql....($Db, $title1);
$title2 = mysql....($Db, $title2);

$joined  = $title1 . '-'. $title2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) in this way.

```
  $title2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$title2);
  $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($DB,$title);
  // Perform a concatenation operation
  $joinedTitle = $title2.'-'.$title;
  echo $joinedTitle;
```

Now save `$joinedTitle` to your DB.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string($var)` that won't work. Edit: you've edit. good ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii: Yes. I have edited my answer. Thanks for your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you are trying to save `"Artist Name - Song Name"` into your database. You are building your SQL query by escaping characters correctly but the function you are calling takes 2 arguments and not 3!

By the way, your jQuery kind of query to get your HTML element seems to be rather long. Can't you make it shorter?

```
$artist = $html2->find('#wrapper div.details > h1 > strong', 0)->plaintext;
$song = $html2->find('#wrapper div.details > h1 > span', 0)->plaintext;
$title = "$artist - $song"; // Or $title = $artist . ' - ' . $song;

print $title;

$sql = 'INSERT INTO your_table (`title`) VALUES (' .
       mysqli_real_escape_string($DB, $title) . ');';
```